# Show a Toast after user has completed multiple AlertDialogs

Tags: java, android

I'm doing the following: Depending on the number of Stock needed to be entered I generate an EditText Dialog.

For example if I enter the number 5 in Stock:

IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP4YL.jpg

I generate a Dialog 5 times where you enter details, and where the title will change as I'm entering data.

IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhE60.jpg

What I do not understand is how I want the title to appear:

- Product 1/5 Product 2/5, 3/5 Product, Product 4/5 Product 5/5.

What I actually get is follows:

- Product 5/5 Product 4/5 Product 3/5, 2/5 Product, Product 1/5.

I also want to show a Toast after the final product is added. The problem is that the Toast shows immediately after the Click event.

My code is as follows:

```
btnContinuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int stock = Integer.parseInt(input_layout_stock.getEditText().getText().toString());
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= stock ; i++){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setTitle("Producto " + i + "/" + stock);
            //builder.setMessage("Agregar");
            builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_add_product);
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_product, null));
            builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
            builder.create();
            if(i == 5){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se agregaron " + stock + " productos con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop doesn't wait for the dialog to be dismissed to create the next one, so the second dialog overlaps the first, and the third overlaps the second, and so on. What you need to do is to show each dialog in the previous dialog's `onDismiss` callback.

I simplified the code to use as an example. You can add the rest of your code back where you need it.

```
private int current = 1; // Global variable



    final int stock = Integer.parseInt("5");
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Producto " + current + "/" + stock);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (current < stock) {
                current++;

                // TODO Create your next dialog here.
                builder.setTitle("Producto " + current + "/" + stock);
                builder.show();
            } else {
                // This was the last dialog. Show Toast.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se agregaron " + stock + " productos con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                current = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, but when I enter a new value in stock, Dialog continues the count and not starting from 1. For example, if I entered first "5" in stock and then enter "10". The continuous dialog from 5 to 10.

Comment: You have to reset the value of `current`  in the else clause. Please check the edited answer (After the Toast).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly you want to start at Product 1/5 then go to Product  5/5, but what you're getting is Product 5/5 down to Product 1/5, correct?

If that's the case the reason you're getting 5/5 first is because that's the last dialog box created (it's covering the previous dialog boxes), and the toast is created because it's in the loop. The loop keeps going even if the user hasn't inputted anything.